# A word that describes a liquid's tendency to form bubbles

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes the property of a liquid that causes it to tend more easily to form long-lasting bubbles?

These liquids are increasing in this property:

> water < milk < bubble solution < liquid soap

*Viscosity* or being *viscous* are a noun and an adjective that describe the property of a liquid/oil's thickness. I'm looking for something similar, but for the bubbly property that I'm describing.

Example usage:

- I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gargle, because *it has a higher ___*.

or

- I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gargle, because *it's more ___*.

Comment: Bubbles foam out when you wash peas because they are full of *saponines*. I suppose you could call that *saponification*. Or something. Just never drop the sapon.

Comment: Look at *lather* (noun or verb). You'll still need another word to go with it, or with anything else you find.

Comment: You could rightfully say that the mouthwash has a _lower surface tension_, or that it is a _better surfactant_ (or _tensioactive_). It may not sound fancy, but at least it will be physically right.

Comment: @wismuthaft That should be written up as the answer.

Comment: Saponification is chemical reaction forming soap.

Comment: If the bubbles are specifically caused by soap or soap-like substances, you could say the liquid is *sudsy*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could rightfully say that the mouthwash has a *lower surface tension*, or that it is a *better surfactant* (or *tensioactive*). It may not sound fancy, but at least it will be physically correct.

The point is whether the bubbling has to be triggered somehow (e.g. by gargling) or not. A *frothy*, *foamy* or *fizzy* liquid is one that gives off bubbles spontaneously, while mouthwash or soap are not foamy as long as they're not shaken.

Comment: "Effervescent" is another word for liquids that bubble without being shaken.

Comment: Sure, but common effervescent liquids bubble because of an ongoing reaction releasing gaseous products, or because a gas already dissolved in it is set free by a change in pressure (when you open a coke can) or temperature (its solubility drops, usually by heating).
I should probably change the second sentence because 'not shaken' is not enough to define a non-bubbling, non-reacting liquid.

Answer (score 22):

> Foaming tendency

This term appears utilized in industry where material properties are critical for function.  (http://www.astm.org/Standards/D892.htm)

For the first replacement:

> I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gurgle, because it has a higher *foaming tendency*.

Second one requires some shoe-horning to get it to fit the sentence.

> I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gurgle, because it's more *likely to foam*.

Reworded

> I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gurgle, because it *has a higher tendency to foam*.

Answer (score 11):

Consider, ***spumescence*** and ***spumescent***.

> spumescent: producing or resembling foam or froth [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spumescent)
>
> *I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gurgle, because it has a higher spumescence*.
>
> *I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gurgle, because it's more spumescent*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spumescent%2Cspumescence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspumescent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspumescence%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: You're really good at finding nominally correct words in English that no one has ever heard of. What resource do you use to search through? OED?

Comment: So this is basically a synonym of foamy, right?

Comment: @nibus Yes, along with being a synonym of foam-producing...

Answer (score 4):

You could try **effervescence**, meaning

> The bubbling of a solution due to the escape of gas. The gas may form by a chemical reaction, as in a fermenting liquid, or by coming out of solution after having been under pressure, as in a carbonated drink.

There is also a verb, effervesce, meaning

> To emit small bubbles of gas, as a carbonated or fermenting liquid.

To use in your sentence:

> I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gargle, because it's more effervescent.

or

> I don't like this mouthwash. Bubbles foam out when I gargle, because it has a higher effervescence

(or level of effervescence, not sure about the usage in that case.)

Comment: This seems to only apply to liquids with compressed gas, which will escape naturally.

Comment: @ Minnow Sorry! I'm not an expert on the science side of things, just remembered hearing the word in connection with bubbles.

Comment: No apologies needed, it's a useful term in the right context.  Given that this is EL&U, the OP may or may not care about scientific accuracy.

Comment: I couldn't help wondering if, all the while we're focused on the proper terms for mouthwash bubbles, aren't we "gargling", not "gurgling"?

Answer (score 4):

While the sentences in Minnow's answer sound nicer to my ear, **foamable** appears to be gaining in popularity over foaming tendency.

[image: ngram- foamable, foaming tendency]

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple,  "bubblier"

I do not like this mouthwash, it is bubblier than others.

Comment: The solution need not have bubbles to be able to form them.  Is soap with no bubbles "bubblier" than water with some bubbles?

Answer (score 1):

*Frothiness* for the noun and *frothy*, *frothier*, and *frothiest* for the adjectives.